# bootstrap wysithml5 with subscript and superscript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5

For my Bootstrap website, I wanna use the [wysihtml 5 editor](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5). But that one doesn't support super-/subscript by default.

This line I added for the editor:

```
<a class='btn' data-wysihtml5-command='superscript'>superscript</a>
```

The following code is a part of the source of the wysihtml5 editor for bootstrap:

`dom.delegate(container, "[data-wysihtml5-command]", "click", function(event) {
        var link          = this,
            command       = link.getAttribute("data-wysihtml5-command"),
            commandValue  = link.getAttribute("data-wysihtml5-command-value");
        that.execCommand(command, commandValue);
        event.preventDefault();
      });`

It does work for everything by default, but not for superscript and subscript.

Google gave me results that I had to use the execCommand with the commandValue set to false, but that also didn't work.

Someone does know how to do the trick to get it to work, that it adds / to the code?

Answer (score 3):

Try SUP instead of SUPERSCRIPT

Answer (score 3):

add the following code to the source https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/blob/master/dist/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js

Modified wysihtm5 with sup and sub

after line 6876 from the source

```
(function (wysihtml5) {
    var undef;

    wysihtml5.commands.sub = {
        exec: function (composer, command) {
            return wysihtml5.commands.formatInline.exec(composer, command, "sub");
        },

        state: function (composer, command, color) {
            // element.ownerDocument.queryCommandState("bold") results:
            // firefox: only <b>
            // chrome:  <b>, <strong>, <h1>, <h2>, ...
            // ie:      <b>, <strong>
            // opera:   <b>, <strong>
            return wysihtml5.commands.formatInline.state(composer, command, "sub");
        },

        value: function () {
            return undef;
        }
    };
})(wysihtml5);
(function (wysihtml5) {
    var undef;

    wysihtml5.commands.sup = {
        exec: function (composer, command) {
            return wysihtml5.commands.formatInline.exec(composer, command, "sup");
        },

        state: function (composer, command, color) {
            // element.ownerDocument.queryCommandState("bold") results:
            // firefox: only <b>
            // chrome:  <b>, <strong>, <h1>, <h2>, ...
            // ie:      <b>, <strong>
            // opera:   <b>, <strong>
            return wysihtml5.commands.formatInline.state(composer, command, "sup");
        },

        value: function () {
            return undef;
        }
    };
})(wysihtml5);
```

and after line 7291 from the source

```
    "sub":    "sub",
    "sup":    "sup"
```

and after line 8441 from the source

```
    "83": "sub", // S
    "80": "sup" // P
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend the above example, you should add to the `bootstrap-wysihtml5.js` at the parserRules the followings:

```
tags: {
                "sub":{},
                "sup":{}..
```